# A date sorting algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, date, comparator

Note, this works, this comparator.  I just wonder whether there is a more elegant way to do it?
Basically I have a LinkeList of dates in the form mm/dd/yyyy (or MM/dd/yyyy).  Doing a regular string sort will, for obvious reasons, not work as 1/1/2015 would come before 12/12/1997.  So I wrote this comparator.

One catch, though.  Sometimes the date could be null (or blank) so it should come first ascending, or last descending.

I wrote this comparator which I send to Collections.sort().  Remember, it does work but there's got to be a simpler way?

Oh, one thing I forgot to mention is this one declaration:

```
public class DateFormats { 
    ...
    public static final SimpleDateFormat PTL_MMddyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    ...
}
```

Comparator follows:

```
public static class dateSort implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String cur, String nxt) {
        String veryEarlyDate = "01/01/0001";
        Date curdate = null;
        Date nxtdate = null;
        cur = ((cur != null && !cur.trim().isEmpty()) ? cur : veryEarlyDate);
        nxt = ((nxt != null && !nxt.trim().isEmpty()) ? nxt : veryEarlyDate);
        try {
            curdate = DateFormats.PTL_MMddyy.parse(cur);
            nxtdate = DateFormats.PTL_MMddyy.parse(nxt);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Bad date " + cur + " or " + nxt);
            assert (false) : e.getMessage();
        }
        return curdate.compareTo(nxtdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just sort a list of `Date` objects, instead of trying to manipulate a list of strings?

Comment: Do you *have* to have a collection of strings instead of a collection of date-based objects (`LocalDate` for example)? In general, it's a good idea to keep data in its "natural" form for as much of the time as possible.

Comment: That is how they are on the html page, MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: There are plenty integers, longs and other numeric elements in HTML pages that are read first as `String`s, that doesn't mean I cannot store them as the real type they are.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement comparable in your DateFormat class. Then, implement the compareTo method and compare the objects. Return 1 if bigger, 0 if equal and -1 if smaller.

```
public class DateFormat implements Comparable{

... 

   public int compareTo(Object o){
       DateFormat df = (DateFormat)o; 
       int result; 
       ... //do desired comparison 
       //and set result to -1, 0 or 1 depending on result.
       return result; 
   }
}
```

Then you could use the Arrays.sort(DateFormat[] dateFormatArray); to sort the collection of DateFormat objects.

Comment: But I would have to write a separate comparator for each date format?

Comment: The purpose of the compareTo method is that all cases are solved for. You should think about all the cases of the DateFormat and compare them and think about how you want to compare them. Implement the comparisons and look for more compareTo examples online for a better idea of how to implement the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got right what you want, but an easy way I could think of is turning the dates into ints and then comparing them.

```
MM/dd/yyyy -> yyyyMMdd (yyyy * 10000 + MM * 100 + dd)
1/1/2015   -> 20150101
12/12/1997 -> 19971212
```

Comment: and blanks and nuls just be 0?  That could work but I still have to manipulate.  Do a split("/") and then Integer.parseInt(fields[2])*10000 + Integer.parseInt(fields[1])*100 + Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);

Answer (score 0):

Java's `Data` and Jodatime's `LocalDate` are already `Comparable`, as such no additional code is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more elegant(simplicity + logical) if your LinkedList used an Object[] instead of String.
When you add the String to the linkedList, parse it at that time.  I would avoid parsing it in the comparator.

```
if(string != null)
    Object[] toAddToList = new Object[]{string, PTL_MMddyyyy.parse(string)};
else
    Object[] toAddToList = new Object[]{null, null};
```

Then

```
    public static class dateSort implements Comparator<Object[]> 
    {
        public int compare(Object[] cur, Object[] nxt) 
        {
           //TODO: add null check
           return ((Date)cur[1]).compareTo((Date)nxt[1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use Date-Time Objects

Some experienced people have suggested a better policy is to work with natural data types rather than strings. Number values should be numeric objects, [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) values should be UUID objects, and date-time values should be date-time objects.

You business logic should utilize these objects. Rendering to strings should happen only for:

- Presentation to the user ([localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization)) (Use [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda.sourceforge.net/api-time/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) in Joda-Time)
- Output to storage or other systems ([serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)) (Use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format)

## Joda-Time

As some folks suggested, [Joda-Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) is the way to go, rather than the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/.Calendar classes bundled with Java. Alternatively, you can use java.time built into Java 8 (inspired by Joda-Time).

## `Comparable`

Joda-Time implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true). So, ready for sorting.

## Example Code

Here is some example Joda-Time 2.6 code.

```
// Simulate input.
List<String> listInput = new ArrayList<>();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
listInput.add( formatter.print( LocalDate.now() ) );
listInput.add( formatter.print( LocalDate.now().plusDays( 5 ) ) );
listInput.add( formatter.print( LocalDate.now().minusDays( 13 ) ) );
```

Convert Strings to [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) objects. This class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
// Convert strings to LocalDate objects.
List<LocalDate> listLocalDate = new ArrayList<>();
for ( String s : listInput ) {
    try {
        LocalDate x = formatter.parseLocalDate( s );
        listLocalDate.add( x );
    } catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
        // …
        // Handle invalid data input.
    }
}
Collections.sort( listLocalDate );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "listInput : " + listInput );
System.out.println( "listLocalDate : " + listLocalDate );
```

When run.

```
listInput : [12/17/2014, 12/22/2014, 12/04/2014]
listLocalDate : [2014-12-04, 2014-12-17, 2014-12-22]
```